# Как вставить слово в текст на php?

Tags: php

Нужно подмешать ключи в текст в случайное место в тексте и желательно выставить количество вставок ключей или в числовой форме или в процентах.
Пытался использовать так:

```
$final_text = str_replace (", ",", keyword ",$text);
```

Но блин, заменяются все запятые и получается переспам, как можно рандомизировать место вставки и контролировать количество вставок?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 3;
$text = 'Some text';
$keyword = '-';
$lengh = strlen($text);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
     $text = substr_replace($text, $keyword, rand(0, $lengh) , 0);
}

echo $text;
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9312f0f04f4b3bc8d7e3916e22e73c4d5973d7f) Нужно еще проверку места добавить, чтобы два подряд не было. Но суть я думаю понятна.

Comment: Попробовал запустить, ключь вставляется не между.словами, а разбивает слова и ставится внутри слов

Comment: Вы писали: "текст в случайное место в тексте"